# Are the following series pointwise convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

I am trying to find the answer to these questions: Are the following series pointwise convergent? If so, how smooth are the functions, i.e. which class $C^k$ are they in? ($C^k$ means that derivatives $f',...,f^k$ exists and are continuous).

The functions:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(\theta) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} \sin n\theta \\
g(\theta) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3} \sin n\theta \\
h(\theta) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n} \cos n\theta
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

What I have done so far is used Weierstrass M test for $g$ and $h$.

For $g(\theta)$: Since

\begin{equation}
0 \leq |\sin n\theta| \leq 1
\end{equation}

We can take $M_n=n^{-3}$. $\sum_{1}^{\infty} M_n$ is convergent, which means that $g(\theta)$ is also convergent. $g(\theta)$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ since we can differentiate $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ forever. The derivative will swap from $\sin n\theta$ to $\cos n\theta$ and switch sign depending on what order it is. It will also accumulate a growing power of $n$ because of the chain rule.

For $h(\theta)$: Since

\begin{equation}
0 \leq |\cos n\theta| \leq 1
\end{equation}

We can take $M_n=3^{-n}$. $\sum_{1}^{\infty} M_n$ is convergent, which means that $h(\theta)$ is also convergent. $h(\theta)$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ by the same argument as for $g(\theta)$.

My questions:

Is my reasoning for $g(\theta)$ and $h(\theta)$ correct? Do you have any tips for $f(\theta)$? Is there another type of test that is applicable? I cannot use the M test as easily since $\sum_{1}^{\infty} (n+1)^{-1}$ is divergent.

For some context:

I am studying Fourier Analysis, and the series look like Fourier cosine and sine expansions. So maybe there is something I have missed in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For $f$. Use [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). You will have to show that the partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(n\,x)$ are bounded.
2. For $g$. The series is uniformly convergent as you showed. But you can differentiate safely only once. The series you obtain differentiating twice is similar to $f$; it is convergent but things are delicate. If you differentiate three times, the series you obtain is not convergent.
3. For $h$. You can derivate tern by term as many times as you want, because the derived series is uniformly convergent by Weierstrass $M$-test.